# For() loop to ID dates that are between others and calculate a mean value

Tags: r, for-loop

This is a re-post of "R: For() loop checking if date is between two dates in separate object", that has been changed to incorporate a mock/test minimal after the suggestions of Henrik and Metrics.  Thanks to them.

I have two large datasets, both contain columns of date/time fields.  My first dataset has a single date, the second has two dates.  In short I am trying to find all dates from the first data set that are between the other two dates of the second and then find an average value.  In order to provide clarity, I have created a mock minimal data set using values rather than dates.

The head() of my first mock data set is below – as well as the dput() output.  The data is specific to an individual noted by the IndID column.

```
  IndID MockDate RandNumber
1     1        5   1.862084
2     1        3   1.103154
3     1        5   1.373760
4     1        1   1.497397
5     1        1   1.319488
6     1        3   2.120354

actData <- structure(list(IndID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), MockDate = c(5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L), RandNumber = c(1.862083679, 1.103154127, 
1.37376001, 1.497397482, 1.319487885, 2.120353884, 1.895660195, 
1.150411874, 2.61036961, 1.99354158, 1.547706758, 1.941501873, 
1.739226419, 2.455590044, 2.907382515, 2.110502618, 2.076187012, 
2.507527308, 2.167657681, 1.662405916, 2.428807116, 2.04699653, 
1.937335768, 1.456518889, 1.948952907, 2.104325112, 2.311519732, 
2.092650229, 2.109051215, 2.089144475)), .Names = c("IndID", 
"MockDate", "RandNumber"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

The head() of my 2nd mock data set is below – as well as the dput() output.

```
 IndID StartTime EndTime
1     1         4       5
2     1         7      11
3     1         6       9
4     1         7       9
5     1         6      10
6     1         2      12

clstrData <- structure(list(IndID.1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), StartTime = c(4L, 7L, 
6L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
5L), EndTime = c(5L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 8L, 13L, 5L, 13L, 
9L, 9L, 17L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 9L, 15L, 7L)), .Names = c("IndID", 
"StartTime", "EndTime"), row.names = c(NA, 19L), class = "data.frame")
```

The second dataset has two number fields representing a start and end time. As above, these data are also specific to an individual noted by the IndD column.

I need to average the ‘RandNumber’ from dataset one for all the instances when ‘MockDate’ is between ‘StartTime’ and ‘EndTime’ of the second dataset for each unique IndID.   Thus, ‘RandNumber’ values should only be averaged if 1) they are within the ‘StartTime’ and ‘EndTime’ and 2) the IndID for both rows are the same.

I started by creating a function to ID if MockDate is between StartTime and EndTime

```
is.between <- function(x, a, b) {
    x > a & x < b
}
```

Testing that function works for a single value
    is.between(actData[1,3], clstrData[,2], clstrData[,3])

But cannot figure out how to loop this for all rows, and then find the mean.  My for() loop beginnings are below.

```
YesNo <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(actData)) {
YesNo[[i]] <- is.between(actData[1,3], clstrData[,2], clstrData[,3])
}
YesNo[[3]]
```

This for() gives the same result for all row…

Hope to create...
    clstrData$NEWcolum <- mean RandNum for each row.

Thanks, and as always any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ricardo Saporta for earlier thoughts.

However, constructing a long conditional in my for() loop was the best option for me - although not as fast as data.table().

Using the data above, the code below is what I ended up constructing.

```
clstrData$meanAct = rep(NA, nrow(clstrData))

for (i in 1:nrow(clstrData)){
    clstrData$meanAct[i] = mean(actData$RandNumber[actData$IndID==clstrData$IndID[i]
    &is.between(actData$RandNumber, clstrData$StartTime[i], clstrData$EndTime[i])])
    }
head(clstrData)
tail(clstrData)
```

Were there is no corresponding value between the Start and End times, NAN's are produced.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your machine can handle the data size, you can:

- merge the two data frames on the ID, then
- group accordingly (ie, by IndID, Start & End dates)
- compute mean for those rows where mock date falls between the end dates

Here is some code using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT.clstr <- data.table(clstrData, key="IndID")
DT.act   <- data.table(actData, key="IndID")

# Adjust to `<=` if needed
ComputedDT <- 
  merge(DT.clstr, DT.act, allow.cartesian=TRUE)[
      MockDate > StartTime &  MockDate < EndTime
    , list(Mean=mean(RandNumber))
    , by=list(IndID, StartTime, EndTime)
    ]
```

#### Results

```
ComputedDT

   IndID StartTime EndTime     Mean
1:     1         2      12 1.671002
2:     2         4      13 2.176799
3:     2         2       9 2.244702
4:     3         3       6 1.978828
5:     3         4       8 1.940887
6:     3         2       9 2.033104
```

Comment: Cool.  Looking at the ?data.table the pkg looks new.  Thanks for sharing.  Your code seems to work fine, but I lose some of the results. The final table needs to have all the rows of the ClstrData.  I figured if I created a unique ID for each cluster, [using clstrData$ClstrID <- c(001:019)] I could add it to the by= field.  Unfortunately, once this field is added the data.table() results in an error.  Any suggestions..  Thanks!

Comment: @user2778289 have a look at the documentation for `?merge.data.table` specifically at the argument `all.x` which sounds like you want to set that to `TRUE`.   To capture IDs/Times where there is no matching "in between" date, you might want to create a wrapper function that runs `mean` if there are values and otherwise returns `NA` if there are no values. -- Feel free to open a new question if you need help with that second part